# cannot add image files to xcode resourse folder

Tags: iphone, xcode

I tried adding images to my xcode resourse folder by drag and drop. But its showing me the error cannot add the image... 
can anyone tell me what is going wrong... i had previously added images like this and that had worked .but now its not working...

Answer (score 1):

Is this by any chance an image you have previously deleted from your project? Occasionally there is a bug that prevents reading them back. If so, open the project.pbxproj file and delete all references to that file, then try to add your image.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific on the error message. Did you check "Copy item to destination's group folder"?